# using "continue" in loop is anti pattern?

Tags: java, loops, continue

Do you think the code below is an anti-pattern? 
condition1, contidion2, condition3 is a different kind of state value.

```
for(Dto dto : list){
    if(condition1(dto.getErrYn())){
        ...code...
        continue;
    }

    if(condition2(dto.getChangeYn())){
        ...code...
        continue;
    }

    if(condition3(dto.getRunYn())){
        ...code...
        continue;
    }
}
```

using "if-else if" is better?

```
for(Dto dto : list){
    if(condition1(dto.getErrYn())){
        ...code...
    }else if(condition2(dto.getChangeYn())){
        ...code...
    }else if(condition3(dto.getRunYn())){
        ...code...
    }
}
```

or using "case" is better?

What do you think is the best way? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What advantages do you think using `continue` would give you? What do **you** think is the best way and why?

Comment: Why do you think `case` can be used in place of `continue`?

Comment: @BackSlash it's about finding novel ways to implement if-else. Now `switch-case` is standard stuff there, but the first code snippet is a beautiful example of thinking outside the box.

Comment: @Kayaman I understand that, but `switch-case` cannot always replace an `if-else`, especially in this scenario, since it seems that all conditions are different, so I don't really understand what makes the OP think a `case` would be better here

Comment: @BackSlash the OP has no idea what to think. That's why he's asking questions like this.

Comment: The best way is to split your code in two functions. One which loop on each DTO, and another which treats the current. In the second function, use `return` or `else if` no matter, the readability will be better anyway.

Comment: The issue with your code is that you should add more OO design, rather than choosing various procedural approach. There is nothing bad with _continue/break_ indise a loop or _if else_ statements. They are just warnings when you start to need more in the same piece of code. They start to multiply branches and made your code complicated, full of duplication, coupled and fragile. Of course even very difficult to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Using `continue` in a loop is not an anti-pattern. However using `continue` like in your first example is just dumb.

For no apparent reason you introduce more lines of code, instead of using the standard `if-else` pattern that everyone will understand. I don't know where you got the idea of using `continue` like that (or maybe you saw it in someone else's code), but that's bad and wrong.

If you want to know the best ways to do things, look at how other (experienced) people do them. Your colleagues may not be the best source of information depending on your place of work.

Comment: when all the conditions are different, I think using 'if-else' reduces readability. So I thought about using 'if-continue'. Is 'if-else' used when comparing multiple values ​​to one condition?

Comment: If your code becomes complex to read, then you probably shouldn't use `if-else`, but refactor the code to something more readable. However convertin that to `if-continue` doesn't make it less bad, it just makes it bad in a different way. It's probably the `condition1` etc. that are poorly designed here, and should be moved to the dto itself or something like that. Hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: I can't show the actual code, so it seems difficult to communicate correctly. But the code inside if statement is very simple. So I thought about using 'if-continue'. I'll think of a better way. Thanks for advice

Comment: Downvoted. "Early Return" pattern is a full analog and is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Advantage of "if-else if" over "continue" approach is that you immediately see that only one of this condition can run. When you require adding "continue" in the end of each condition someone can just forget it.
When it comes to "swith case" it's consider as code smell in OOP languages.
Here you have nice article about it:
http://wiki.c2.com/?SwitchStatementsSmell

Comment: *When you require adding "continue" in the end of each condition someone can just forget it* - if your code block is that long that after reading it you forgot what was the condition that triggered it, you have different problems